# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck in low graphics mode

Tags: boot, 16.04, graphics, display, intel-graphics

I am stuck in low graphics mode and can't get out!

I have tried many solutions that I have found, so far none work. I looked at my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` and this is what it said: [image: Xorg log] I have no idea what to do at this point, I tried to reinstall desktop and nothing. Thanks for any help. I can get in tool terminal with `Control+Alt+F5` I have a Intel graphics card. Not sure what kind of card exactly. Laptop is a HP Mini 2GB ram 500Gb HDD. It worked for a while before. Last thing I rember doing was `sudo apt-get update` than a reboot

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: How do I get out of low graphics mode

Comment: See if  this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) helpful.

Comment: That was actually the most recent one I tried, still nothing.